# AttributeError: Cannot access attribute 'str' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Tags: python, pandas

i hv a dataframe that i got from groupby. now i need to convert the string in rows to separate columns. i used this :

```
df5 = pd.DataFrame([df4['notes'].str], columns = df4['id'])

print (df5.head())
```

but getting that error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.